# Call one controller from another without reloading it

Tags: ember.js

I need to call one controller from another.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs   : ['another'],
  ....
  callAnother: function() {
    this.get('controllers.another').reloadIt();
  }
})
```

Another controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function() {
     calling API
  },
  reloadIt: function() {
    calling API
  }
})
```

When I call `this.get('controllers.another').reloadIt()`. It calls `init` and `reloadIt`.

Is it possible to call it without `init` because it's already loaded.

Thanks.

Comment: trying to understand your question. So you trying to access reloadIt{} property in your controller?

Comment: @JosephCC, I need to reload `Another` controller from the first controller in some cases. For example, I click on button and the first controller calls `callAnother`. `callAnother` should call `reloadIt` in another controller. `reloadIt` calls API and reload content.

Comment: @JosephCC, But now when I call `reloadIt` Another controller calls `init` and `reloadIt`. In `reloadIt` I set new properties - `setProperties` but a template is not updating...

Comment: so you are trying to access a single property in this case reloadIt and not init. right?

Comment: yes, just `reloadIt` because my controller on a page already. I have a page with two sections - two controllers, two templates. And if I click a button on one section I should reload(call API with another data) the second.

Comment: If `init` is being called, it doesn't sound like the controller was already instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using macros for this purpose is a lot easier.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs   : ['another'],

 callAnother: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.another.reloadIt'),

 actions:{

    callController: function(){
       this.get('callAnother');
     },

  }
})
```

Comment: Let me know if that works. Also search for ember macros, makes life a lot easier

Comment: woohoo, thank you so much. Now it doesn't call `init`, only `reloadIt`. But now I have another problem. If in template I use `{{anotherVar}}`, and if in `reloadIt` I set `anotherVar` - `this.set('anotherVar', 'something new')` template is not updating...

Comment: try this this.set('anotherVar', somethingNew)

Comment: and please if I answer your question, mark your question as answered

Comment: is your template now updating?

Comment: no, I use in Another controller - `export default Ember.Controller.extend({ anotherVar: 'first'`, and in template it shows `first`. Everything is good. But in `reloadIt` I use `this.set('anotherVar', 'second')`. And template shows `first`.

Comment: Ah, `this.get('callAnother');` doesn't call the function. I can see the function in console - `console.log(this.get('callAnother'))` but it doesn't call it.