# Can't update template from controller

Tags: ember.js

I need to update template from action. But I use two controllers.

In my template I show a text:

```
{{myText}}
```

My controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   myText: 'Hi',
   actions: {
    reload: function() {
        this.set('myText', 'Bye');
    }
   }
   ...
```

I change it from another controller from `someFun`:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['another'],
    someFun: function() {
        this.get('controllers.another').send('reload');
    }
});
```

It calls `reload` action (I tested). But it doesn't change template. It still shows `Hi` but should change to `Bye`.

Comment: Your code should work. When you call `someFun`?

Comment: You should look into [services](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/applications/services/) instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call one controller from another without reloading it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085510/call-one-controller-from-another-without-reloading-it)

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure what you want to achieve. But I made a twiddle for different use cases:

https://ember-twiddle.com/acdeae68da87c11ad152702cd2f8fddd?openFiles=routes.my-fun.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-fun

You either want to handle the event when routing away from /my-fun or on a button click. Both use cases can be taken from the twiddle.
The `needs` is a legacy from old ember versions. Newer Versions of ember should make use of the `inject.controller`...